# Poetry unable to install hydra

Tags: python, python-poetry, hydra

Poetry can not install hydra with the below error. How to install Hydra with poetry:

```
$ poetry add hydra
                                                                                                          
Using version ^2.5 for hydra

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (6.3s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing hydra (2.5): Failed

  CalledProcessError

  Command '['/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--isolated', '--no-input', '--prefix', '/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9', '--no-deps', '/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/d8/9a/72/7404c4669ad6d023f10626f1f4ad5a0f0bb0fe11b6e4ec7fe398dff895/Hydra-2.5.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:528 in run
       524│             # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
       525│             raise
       526│         retcode = process.poll()
       527│         if check and retcode:
    →  528│             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
       529│                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
       530│     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
       531│ 
       532│ 

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--isolated', '--no-input', '--prefix', '/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9', '--no-deps', '/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/d8/9a/72/7404c4669ad6d023f10626f1f4ad5a0f0bb0fe11b6e4ec7fe398dff895/Hydra-2.5.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/d8/9a/72/7404c4669ad6d023f10626f1f4ad5a0f0bb0fe11b6e4ec7fe398dff895/Hydra-2.5.tar.gz
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Building wheels for collected packages: Hydra
    Building wheel for Hydra (pyproject.toml): started
    Building wheel for Hydra (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Building wheel for Hydra (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [221 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39
        copying src/hydra.py -> build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39
        running build_ext
        building '_hydra' extension
        creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39
        creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39/src
        clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -I/private/var/folders/1y/w1f378ln3js1n9dhwbwshkm40000gn/T/pip-req-build-owvns8k8/src -I/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/MurmurHash3.c -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39/src/MurmurHash3.o -std=gnu99 -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
        clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -I/private/var/folders/1y/w1f378ln3js1n9dhwbwshkm40000gn/T/pip-req-build-owvns8k8/src -I/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_hydra.c -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39/src/_hydra.o -std=gnu99 -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
        src/_hydra.c:3377:36: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-compare]
          __pyx_t_3 = ((__pyx_v_self->_idx < __pyx_t_2) != 0);
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
        src/_hydra.c:7137:44: warning: taking the absolute value of unsigned type 'unsigned long' has no effect [-Wabsolute-value]
            (__pyx_v__bucket_indexes[__pyx_v_i]) = llabs((__pyx_t_7 % __pyx_v_max));
                                                   ^
        src/_hydra.c:7137:44: note: remove the call to 'llabs' since unsigned values cannot be negative
            (__pyx_v__bucket_indexes[__pyx_v_i]) = llabs((__pyx_t_7 % __pyx_v_max));
                                                   ^~~~~
        src/_hydra.c:8530:35: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
          __pyx_type_6_hydra_MMapBitField.tp_print = 0;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
        src/_hydra.c:8535:31: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
          __pyx_type_6_hydra_MMapIter.tp_print = 0;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
        src/_hydra.c:8539:40: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
          __pyx_type_6_hydra_BloomCalculations.tp_print = 0;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
        src/_hydra.c:8551:34: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
          __pyx_type_6_hydra_BloomFilter.tp_print = 0;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
        src/_hydra.c:9924:22: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                             ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
              ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9924:22: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                             ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                     ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9924:22: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                             ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
               PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
               ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9924:52: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                           ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
              ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9924:52: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                           ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                     ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9924:52: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                           ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
               PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
               ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9940:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                 ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
              ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9940:26: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                 ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                     ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9940:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                 ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
               PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
               ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9940:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                  ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
              ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9940:59: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                  ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
              ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                     ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:9940:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                  ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
               PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
               ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
        #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                          ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:11521:9: warning: 'PyCFunction_Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                return PyCFunction_Call(func, arg, kw);
                       ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/methodobject.h:33:1: note: 'PyCFunction_Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyCFunction_Call(PyObject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        src/_hydra.c:11586:41: warning: 'PyCFunction_Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            __pyx_CyFunctionType_type.tp_call = PyCFunction_Call;
                                                ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/methodobject.h:33:1: note: 'PyCFunction_Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyCFunction_Call(PyObject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);
        ^
        /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                             ^
        16 warnings and 4 errors generated.
        error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
        [end of output]
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for Hydra
  Failed to build Hydra
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for Hydra, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1540 in _run
      1536│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1537│                     command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env, **kwargs
      1538│                 )
      1539│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1540│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1541│ 
      1542│         return decode(output)
      1543│ 
      1544│     def execute(self, bin: str, *args: str, **kwargs: Any) -> int:

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  PoetryException

  Failed to install /Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/d8/9a/72/7404c4669ad6d023f10626f1f4ad5a0f0bb0fe11b6e4ec7fe398dff895/Hydra-2.5.tar.gz

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/utils/pip.py:58 in pip_install
       54│ 
       55│     try:
       56│         return environment.run_pip(*args)
       57│     except EnvCommandError as e:
    →  58│         raise PoetryException(f"Failed to install {path.as_posix()}") from e
       59│
```

Poetry config:

```
$ poetry env info                                                                                                           

Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.16
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9
Executable:     /Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/showcase-project-lis5iaDt-py3.9/bin/python
Valid:          True

System
Platform:   darwin
OS:         posix
Python:     3.9.16
Path:       /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
Executable: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
```

MacBook M1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you trying to install the Hydra configuration framework (https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra)?

The [`hydra`](https://pypi.org/project/Hydra/) package on pypi.org is unrelated to the Hydra configuration framework. The package you want  is [`hydra-core`](https://pypi.org/project/hydra-core/); you'll need to do `poetry add hydra-core`, not `poetry add hydra`.